# Render component after change in another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components, lifecycle

In my app I am adding new product. But after I click second time it appears on a list. In AddProducts I console.log the array with changed list and it had been updated. But in mu ProductList it doesnt work after click Add so I apply componentDidUpdate to react on changes. Also I use useEffect in App to react on changes sending from AddProduct but it works only I click second times.

**AddProduct**

```
function AddProducts(props) {
  const [newProduct, setNewProduct] = useState({
    productName: ``,
    category: ``,
    groceries: false,
  });
  const [newList, setNewList] = useState(props.productsToDisplay);

  function handleChange(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setNewProduct({
      ...newProduct,
      [event.target.name]:
        event.target.type === "checkbox"
          ? event.target.checked
          : event.target.value,
    });
  }

  function handleAddNewProduct() {
    const addProduct = newList.concat([
      {
        nazwa: newProduct.productName,
        kategoria: newProduct.category,
        produktSpozywczy: newProduct.groceries,
      },
    ]);
    setNewList(addProduct);
    props.sendNewProductsToParent(newList);
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.Wrapper}>
      {console.log(newList)}
      <p>Add products</p>
      <input
        name="productName"
        value={newProduct.productName}
        onChange={handleChange}
      ></input>
      <input
        name="category"
        value={newProduct.category}
        onChange={handleChange}
      ></input>
      <input
        name="groceries"
        type="checkbox"
        value={newProduct.groceries}
        onChange={handleChange}
      ></input>
      <p>Is it groceries?</p>
      <button onClick={handleAddNewProduct}>Add new product</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**ProductList**

```
class ProductsList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={commonColumnsStyles.App}>
        {console.log(this.props.productsToDisplay)}
        <header className={commonColumnsStyles.AppHeader}>
          <p>Products list</p>
          <ul>
            {this.props.productsToDisplay.map((currProduct, index) => (
              <li key={index} onClick={() => this.addProduct(index)}>
                {currProduct.nazwa}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```
function App() {
  const [resultToDisplay, setResultToDisplay] = useState(``);
  const [newProductsList, setNewProductsList] = useState(produkty);

  return (
    <div className={styles.appWrapper}>
      {console.log(newProductsList)}
      <AddProducts
        productsToDisplay={produkty}
        sendNewProductsToParent={setNewProductsList}
      />
      <div className={styles.columnsWrapper}>
        <ProductsList
          productsToDisplay={newProductsList}
          sendAddedProductsToParent={setResultToDisplay}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why is there an infinite loop in the `App` component?

Comment: In AddProducts Im sending {produkty} due to I want add new one. After that I have added some new products Im sending them back to App for ProductList where it should be re render and display on screen (productsToDisplay={newProductsList}). Line sendAddedProductsToParent={setResultToDisplay} is for something else and I forgot to delete.

Comment: `useEffect` in `App` component doesn't do anything

Comment: Remove the state from `ProductsList` and everything will work

Comment: I have deleted states from ProductsList and useEffects. It adds new items but it appears after I click two times on button.

Comment: `props.sendNewProductsToParent(addProduct)`

Comment: Toy should remove `newList` state as well

Comment: Okey it works and it appears immediately. Now, am trying to concat new product with old array. Should I do it in App using somehow useEffect or should I send this new product to ProductList and here try to concat?

Comment: You can pass a function as a parameter `props.sendNewProductsToParent(list => [...list,  { nazwa: newProduct.productName, kategoria: newProduct.category, produktSpozywczy: newProduct.groceries } ])`

Comment: So in general "list" is some kind of previousProps which I apply in useState?

Answer (score 0):

Solution for community:
**AddProduct**

```
function AddProducts(props) {
  const [newProduct, setNewProduct] = useState({
    productName: ``,
    category: ``,
    groceries: false,
  });

  function handleChange(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setNewProduct({
      ...newProduct,
      [event.target.name]:
        event.target.type === "checkbox"
          ? event.target.checked
          : event.target.value,
    });
  }

  function handleAddNewProduct() {
    const addProduct = {
      nazwa: newProduct.productName,
      kategoria: newProduct.category,
      produktSpozywczy: newProduct.groceries,
    };
    props.sendNewProductToParent((listOfPrimiaryProducts) => [
      ...listOfPrimiaryProducts,
      addProduct,
    ]);
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.Wrapper}>
      <p>Add products</p>
      <input
        name="productName"
        value={newProduct.productName}
        onChange={handleChange}
      ></input>
      <input
        name="category"
        value={newProduct.category}
        onChange={handleChange}
      ></input>
      <input
        name="groceries"
        type="checkbox"
        value={newProduct.groceries}
        onChange={handleChange}
      ></input>
      <p>Is it groceries?</p>
      <button onClick={handleAddNewProduct}>Add new product</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AddProducts;
```

**ProductList**

```
class ProductsList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={commonColumnsStyles.App}>
        <header className={commonColumnsStyles.AppHeader}>
          <p>Products list</p>
          <ul>
            {this.props.productsInShop.map((currProduct, index) => (
              <li key={index} onClick={() => this.addProduct(index)}>
                {currProduct.nazwa}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ProductsList;
```

**App**

```
function App() {
  const [productsList, setProductsList] = useState(produkty);

  return (
    <div className={styles.appWrapper}>
      <AddProducts sendNewProductToParent={setProductsList} />
      <div className={styles.columnsWrapper}>
        <ProductsList
          productsInShop={productsList}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).